# Is this ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso the correct version to download?

Tags: 14.04

How to switch from Linux mint 9 isadora to ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso. I do not have a cd.

I have a Acer Netbook with usb.

Is this ubuntu 14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso the correct version to download?  I am new to ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to substitute mint with ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, using Acer Netbook.  Only have usb.  Is Ubuntu-14.04.1-destop-i386.iso the correct version to download.  OS is Linux Mint 9 isadora,

Comment: It depends on the hardware. Xubuntu 14.04.1 may be a better choice.

Comment: Also, if you have an amd64/64-bit processor, you might want to try the 64-bit version instead.

Comment: I have Acer Netbook Intel Atom 1.60 GHz/800.00MHz and 1.5GB memory. It is 32 bit processor.

Answer (score 1):

Lets break apart the file name: `14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso`

`14.04.1` is the most current stable version of Ubuntu available for download.
So you would be encouraged to download and install that version.

`desktop` is best for most users that want to run Ubuntu on their laptop and want to use a graphical user interface.
For a beginner, this is recommended.

`i386` is a 32-bit image and should be used if you computer does not support 64-bit software.

`amd64` is a 64-bit image and can be used if your hardware supports it. This version may provide better performance.

To find out if your hardware supports 64-bit, you can check within the BIOS. Or any site that details the computer's features. This capability is a property of the CPU so in the case that you don't have stock hardware, the CPU is the hardware to research.

*Bottom line:* 
`14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso` is a good choice.

However if your computer can support a 64-bit OS, `14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` may provide better performance.